# Laravel 4 return FatalErrorException after dump-autoload

Tags: php, exception, laravel, routes

thanks for read.
I was creating a model in Laravel 4 while run dump-autoload with Artisan and everything stop working.

I was searching a lot how to fix this problem but i cant find any solution.

I was uninstall Laravel and install again, the problem solved but when i repeat the process, the problem appears again.

Sorry about my english.

The error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::deleted()

The line:

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:281
>
> $this->{$route['verb']}($route['uri'], $action);

My model:

```
<?php
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
class Programacion extends Ardent {

  /**
   * Ardent validation rules
   */
  public static $rules = array(
    'autor' => 'required',
   'etiquetas' => 'required',
    'sala_id' => 'required|integer',
    'genero_id' => 'required|integer',
    'teatro_id' => 'required|integer',
    'img_portada' => 'required',
    'img_miniatura' => 'required',
    'estado' => 'required|integer',
    'referencia' => 'required'
  );
```

}

My method in controller:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postCreate()
{
    $programacion = Programacion::create(
        Input::all()
    );
         //$post = Input::all();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this problem yesterday. My problem was that a Controller class had the same name that a Model class. I renamed the Controller class, ran `php artisan dump-autoload` and it worked again.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me rompí la cabeza tratando de buscarle la vuelta a esto y era de lo mas simple la solución. Devuelta gracias !

Thank you so much, i spent a lot of time trying to fix this.

Comment: Hola Pablo, soy Colombiano, jahhajhja, otro truco cuando tengas que cambiar el nombre de una clase por alguna razón es: Cambia el nombre de la clase `class Nombre`, luego corre dump-autoload, luego cambia el nombre del archivo que quede igual con el de la clase y corre de nuevo dump-autoload.

Comment: could you --please-- answer English on an English forum? thanks